# How can I speed up this directory listing function?

Tags: c++

I list the files of a drive with the following code. It works but it's very slow.
How can I speed it up?

```
void l(string& foldername, vector<string>& output) {
    DIR* dir;
    struct dirent* DirEntry;

    if ((dir = opendir(foldername.c_str())) != NULL)
    {
        while ((DirEntry = readdir(dir)) != NULL)
        {
            if (strcmp(DirEntry->d_name, ".") && strcmp(DirEntry->d_name, ".."))
            {
                string subfolder(foldername);
                subfolder += "\\";
                subfolder += DirEntry->d_name;
                DIR* subdir;
                if ((subdir = opendir(subfolder.c_str())) != NULL)
                {
                    l(subfolder, output);
                    closedir(subdir);
                }
                else
                {
                    string fullname(foldername);
                    fullname = fullname + '\\' + DirEntry->d_name;
                    output.push_back(fullname);
                }
            }
        }
        closedir(dir);
    }
    else
    {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using a recent C++ standard (>=C++17), you could simply use `std::filesystem`. With the help of `std::filesystem::recursive_directory_iterator(path)` its way easier and and you can achieve what you want in less lines of code.

Concerning speed, I guess its more less the fastest implementation, since it is in the standard library. See for example:

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/recursive_directory_iterator